# using mongoclient with multi mongos to connect to a sharded replica mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In a regular sharded replica cluster, it consists of `10 mongos`, `5 config servers` and `10 shards`. I use mongo client to connect to multiple mongos instances.

I have two questions.
**The first question:** What is load policy in this situation? Is it round-robin scheduing?
**The second one:** What if one onf the mongos instances is down, what is the move that mongoclient would take? Will it still connect to this mongos instance or drop this one from the list.

Please help with these.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `mongos` servers provide a *routing service* to direct read/write queries to the appropriate shard(s).

You are specifying multiple `mongos`'s to connect to the MongoDB sharded cluster. An available `mongos` will be used to connect to the server.

> The first question: What is load policy in this situation? Is it
>   round-robin scheduling?

The client will connect to the server with an available `mongos`. There is no "load policy" and there is no round-robin scheduling. You use multiple `mongos`'s for high availability.

See: [Number of mongos and Distribution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/#number-of-mongos-and-distribution)

> The second one: What if one of the mongos instances is down, what is
>   the move that mongoclient would take? Will it still connect to this
>   mongos instance or drop this one from the list.

If a `mongos` is down, the client will connect to the server using another available `mongos` from the list (you have more than one `mongos` to connect with).